# How to stop script with false?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<span id="click">click</span>


$("#click").click(function(){

    if($("#text").val().length < 1){
       alert("click is empty!");
       false;
    }

    alert("ok");
})
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Be8a/

Why in this example if $click length == 0 i have alert click is empty (this is good) and next alert ok (not good) - why false doesnt stop script? 
I know - i can use **else**, but is possible stop with false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the key word `return` to exit the function.

```
$("#click").click(function(){

    if($("#text").val().length < 1){
       alert("click is empty!");
       return false; //Exits the function
    }

    //This will not execute if ($("#text").val().length < 1) == true
    alert("ok");
});
```

**Additional Information**

- You may also want to check out the [MDN docs on `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).
- As suggested in the comments, it would be "best" to add an `else` that returns true. Example:

  ```
  $("#click").click(function(){

     if($("#text").val().length < 1){
         alert("click is empty!");
         return false; //Exits the function
      }
      else {
          alert("ok");
          return true; //Exits the function
      }
  });
  ```

Essentially, in a jQuery handler, `return true` is the same as returning nothing (jQuery will take no action). `return false` is the equivalent of `event.stopPropagation()`.

I suggest reading [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) to gain a better understanding of what's really going on when you use `return false`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to `return false;`:

```
$("#click").click(function(){

    if($("#text").val().length < 1){
       alert("click is empty!");
       return false;
    }

    alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you have to use `return false;` if you want to end the function at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
if($("#text").val().length < 1){
   alert("click is empty!");
   return false;
}

alert("ok");
```